# Send Ctrl+C to a proccess started within java

Tags: java, process, cmd, pid

I want to be able to kill a ping started from my java program, but I need to get the pid to do so. I also did some research and I found out that I can use [SendSignal.exe](http://www.latenighthacking.com/projects/2003/sendsignal/) to send Ctl+C, but I need the pid of the process that I have just started. Is there a way in Java to get the pid?

```
    Process p = null;
    InputStream processOutput;
    BufferedReader reader = null;
    String line = " ";

    p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c " + command);
    processOutput = p.getInputStream();
    reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(processOutput));
    // Read the input
    while((line = reader.readLine()) != null){
        output += line + "\n";
        System.out.println(line);

    }
```

Comment: Thank you.  That helped me. Not sure why I didn't see it during my google search.

Comment: No worries. I've done it a lot of times too.

Comment: Not really a duplicate of that question, as this question is about the PID of a child process rather than the PID of the current process.

Answer (score 1):

Runtime.exec(...) returns a Process object.  Would it help if you called process.destroy()?